Error: No authentication handler is registered for the scheme 'OpenIdConnect'. MSGraph API call from ASP.NET Core MVC web app
I have followed the recommended setup on the MS git project for accessing MSGraph from ASP.NET Core MVC and my hosted app works fine for accessing the web app and initially the MS Graph function (I am using MS Graph to access Sharepoint and save a file to a library).  I am using on behalf of authorisation flows in Microsoft.Identity.Web and believe that my configuration in the Azure Portal is correct because initially everything works correctly.
When debugging through Visual Studio this works fine with no issues and if needed, it will redirect me to login again as necessary, but the hosted app after the token times out (approx. 1 hour) just shows the following error:

InvalidOperationException: No authentication handler is registered for the scheme 'OpenIdConnect'. The registered schemes are: AppServicesAuthentication. Did you forget to call AddAuthentication().AddSomeAuthHandler?
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService.ChallengeAsync(HttpContext context, string scheme, AuthenticationProperties properties).

My startup is as follows:
services.AddOptions();

string[] initialScopes = Configuration.GetValue<string>("MicrosoftGraph:Scopes")?.Split(' ');
    services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(options =>
        {
            Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options);

            // This causes the signin to prompt the user for which
            // account to use - useful when there are multiple accounts signed
            // into the browser
            options.Prompt = "select_account";

            options.Events.OnTokenValidated = async context =>
            {
                var tokenAcquisition = context.HttpContext.RequestServices
                    .GetRequiredService<ITokenAcquisition>();

                var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(
                    new BaseBearerTokenAuthenticationProvider(
                        new TokenAcquisitionTokenProvider(
                            tokenAcquisition,
                            initialScopes,
                            context.Principal)));
            };

            options.Events.OnAuthenticationFailed = context =>
            {
                var error = WebUtility.UrlEncode(context.Exception.Message);
                context.Response
                    .Redirect($"/Home/ErrorWithMessage?message=Authentication+error&debug={error}");
                context.HandleResponse();

                return System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FromResult(0);
            };

            options.Events.OnRemoteFailure = context =>
            {
                if (context.Failure is OpenIdConnectProtocolException)
                {
                    var error = WebUtility.UrlEncode(context.Failure.Message);
                    context.Response
                        .Redirect($"/Home/ErrorWithMessage?message=Sign+in+error&debug={error}");
                    context.HandleResponse();
                }

                return System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FromResult(0);
            };
        })
        .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(options =>
    {
        Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options);
    },
initialScopes)
        .AddMicrosoftGraph(options =>
    {
        options.Scopes = initialScopes;
    })

    // Use in-memory token cache
    // See https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web/wiki/token-cache-serialization
        .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();`

I have also tried the simpler:
services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(Configuration)
        .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(initialScopes)
        .AddMicrosoftGraph(Configuration.GetSection("DownstreamApi"))
        .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();

which resulted in similar errors regarding authentication handlers.
I am using the following packages and versions:
<PackageReference Include="Azure.Identity" Version="1.11.4" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect" Version="6.0.22" NoWarn="NU1605" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Graph" Version="5.42.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Graph.Core" Version="3.1.8" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Web" Version="2.17.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Web.GraphServiceClient" Version="2.17.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI" Version="2.17.0" />

Any help/advice on how to proceed will be gratefully received, this is making me pull my hair out because I can't reproduce it in VS debug or find documentation which helps
I have tried several different versions of Startup and added the Graph TokenAcquisitionTokenProvider class as given in an example on the web, but not joy.

Hi @user28164231, it works fine on local. Did you get such exception when host on Azure App Service? If so, make sure ARR Affinity is enabled (or use sticky sessions) if using in-memory caching. This setting ensures requests from a user session hit the same instance.

Thanks for the tip.  I think it may be code related as I am also running a second instance (on a previous code version) which works fine in Azure App Services using the same Entra App Identity provider
